# Building a web server with old pc

Tags: webserver

i have an old pc with this specs processor AMD a6 7400k, 8gbs of ddr3 1800mhz, wd ssd 240gb 520mb read/ 480 write.
I want to know if with this installing ubuntu, Nginx, how I can measure how much low traffic web sites made in react I can host in it, also some API with nodejs. My internet connection is 300mbs.

o a better question maybe could be, if with this setup I can host some low traffic webpages/API and some development webpages

Comment: So, your question is, how many websites made using react and node.js can I host on a system like this? If so, that is going to be a very difficult question to answer. It depends on so many different variables that it would be basically impossible to give an accurate answer.

Comment: maybe a better question could be if this setup is good to setup server with some pages

Comment: Yes you should be able to run a linux webserver on hardware with those specs, without too much trouble. it won't support lots of sessions and may be slow for complex request processing, but provided the hardware functions, its more than enough. I have linux VMs with 2 vcores and 1GB VRAM that will run low-use web applications.